# Flush kernel buffers for stdout

Tags: c++, linux-kernel

I am learning about Kernel buffers and understand that when we write to a file, it doesn't necessarily go immediately to the file even after flushing; it gets put in a kernel buffer which at some point later will be flushed.  Apparently we can call `fsync()` to flush the kernel buffers, so I experimented with this as follows:

```
/* This works fine, nRet is 0 */
FILE* file = fopen("MyFile", "w");
fprintf(file, "1234");
fflush(file);
int nRet = fsync(fileno(file));

/* This doesn't work, nRet is -1 and errno is 22 (Invalid argument)*/
fprintf(stdout, "Output to standard out");
fflush(stdout);
int p = fileno(stdout);
nRet = fsync(p);
```

I am fully aware that we don't strictly need to flush the kernel buffers, but this is purely a learning experience.

I can't find anything that says that `fsync()` doesn't work on standard output; surely it must do anyway as we might want to provide a super fast update to a console, in which case this would be needed if we hadn't opened the output to the console with `O_SYNC`...

Can someone explain what is happening please?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: fflush for streams, fsync for files.

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at here.  `fflush` flushes user space buffers, whereas `fsync` flushes the kernel buffers.. The thing being flushed can be a stream or a file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html) says:

> **EINVAL**
>   *fd* is bound to a special file which does not support
>   synchronization.

The console device is not a normal file and does not have kernel buffers; any writes are handled immediately by the console driver.
If this were not the case, code like this would not work:

```
printf("Please enter something: ");
scanf(...);
```

Comment: Um, ok.  But many times I have made calls to `printf()` that have returned, yet I am still to see the output on the console...also I don't get what your example shows.  They are two different streams being used there, so I don't see what you mean by "would not work"...can you please elaborate?

Comment: If the console were not synchronous, the prompt would not show.

Comment: By prompt, do you mean the cursor, or the message that is being printed?  Even so, I have definitely printed stuff before that hasn't immediately shown up when run in a debugger, so I'm not sure this is right.  (I don't mean to sound disrespectful, **thank you very much for helping**, it's just that I really want to understand this.)

Comment: The message. (Please note that the C runtime automatically runs `fflush(stdout)` before reading from `stdin`, but we are talking about `fsync` here.)

Comment: OK.  But I am still not sure I have gotten an answer.  If the CRT flushes output automatically before `scanf` that means data has gone to Kernel buffers.  But who has flushed those in order to get the data to appear on the console?  That's why I thought we needed to use `fsync`, but that doesn't work!?

Comment: The console *does not have* kernel buffers.

Comment: OK.  1) Where is this stated please?  2) This being the case, then after a `fflush` the user-mode buffers are emptied straight to console right? 3) `printf` still buffers the data until a flush, correct?  This would explain what I said I see with data not immediately appearing after a `printf` call.

Comment: 1. Devices (i.e., not files) always handle data as soon as they receive it. 2. Yes. 3. Yes.

Comment: Great.  Can you please update your answer with your last two comments as they would greatly help others who may not be inclined to read through comments.